# Create mapping for every class that its name ends with something

Tags: nhibernate, automapper

I want to tell `AutoMapper` to map every class that its name ends with Proxy in a similar way. I want this to get rid of NHibernate Proxy classes and return its initial POCO class.

How can I tell automapper to do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on a solution that is based on a suffix. Instead, you can create maps based on the `INHibernateProxy` interface. Considering that you already have a map from an `EntityClass` to a given `PocoClass`, it would look something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<INHibernateProxy, PocoClass>()
      .ConstructUsing(x => Mapper.Map<PocoClass>(Convert.ChangeType(x.HibernateLazyInitializer.GetImplementation(), x.HibernateLazyInitializer.PersistentClass)));
```